# Merge 2 XML including unmatched nodes

Tags: xslt

I have two XML files, **a** and **b**. I want to merge at a certain child level, Some nodes have attributes. When node names and attributes match, I want the child nodes to be copied. If there are unmatched nodes, I want those also. I present here an example where all nodes of **a** are copied, but I only get matched nodes of **b** (they are merged). How do I get the unmatched nodes of **b**?

File **a.xml**:

```
<level0>
  <level1>
    <level2 value="21">
      <level3 value="31">
        <a>A31</a>
      </level3>
      <level3 value="32">
        <a>A32</a>
      </level3>
    </level2>
    <level2 value="22">
      <level3 value="33">
        <a>A33</a>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</level0>
```

File **b.xml**:

```
<level0>
  <level1>
    <level2 value="21">
      <level3 value="31">
        <b>B31</b>
      </level3>
    </level2>
    <level2 value="22">
      <level3 value="33">
        <b>B33</b>
      </level3>
      <level3 value="34">
        <b>B34</b>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</level0>
```

Using XSL (below), I can merge **b** onto **a**, but this node from **b** is dropped, because there is no match in **a**:

```
<level3 value="34">
  <b>B34</b>
</level3>
```

My output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<level0>
  <level1>
    <level2 value="21">
      <level3 value="31">
        <a>A31</a>
      <b>B31</b></level3>
      <level3 value="32">
        <a>A32</a>
      </level3>
    </level2>
    <level2 value="22">
      <level3 value="33">
        <a>A33</a>
      <b>B33</b></level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</level0>
```

Here is my current XSL. Run it: **xsltproc ab.xsl b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="with" select="'b.xml'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level3">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <xsl:variable name="info" select="document($with)//*/level2[@value=current()/../@value]/level3[@value=current()/@value]/." />
            <xsl:for-each select="$info/*">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I'll bet this is easy, but XSL is not my thing, I rarely need to use it.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Where exactly would `<level3 value="34">` go? I can see a pattern behind your attributes.

Comment: It should go just where it is in the input - under level2 value="22". Maybe I have overthought this. All nodes of both A and B need to be preserved, so I'm just looking for a union. The solution that I have so far outputs all of A plus the common level3 nodes of A and B (it's not an intersection, what is it?). Right now I'll go look for union solutions. Does that sound correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no need to write your own merge stylesheet. Use the merge algorithm that was developed by Oliver Becker. You find the code online [here](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html).

The easiest way to run the stylesheet is to create an XML file that summarizes which files should be merged:

**Summary Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<merge xmlns="http://informatik.hu-berlin.de/merge">
   <file1>a.xml</file1>
   <file2>b.xml</file2>
</merge>
```

When applied to both of your input files, this is the output I get:

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><level0>
  <level1>
    <level2 value="21">
      <level3 value="31">
        <a>A31</a>
      <b>B31</b>
      </level3>
      <level3 value="32">
        <a>A32</a>
      </level3>
    </level2>
    <level2 value="22">
      <level3 value="33">
        <a>A33</a>
      <b>B33</b>
      </level3>
    <level3 value="34">
        <b>B34</b>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</level0>
```

The output differs from your expected output in one respect: `<level3 value="34">` is not present in the expected output, as pointed out by @LegoStormtroopr already.

Note that "intersection" and "union" in XSLT (or XML in general) are not necessarily the same concepts as in SQL.

Comment: Yikes!!! That solution by Oliver Becker is one huge XSL. I never would have come close to a solution like that. It does just what I need (I have a far more complex set of input files than my example). Thank you so much for pointing me to it.